# How should I go about buying a guitar?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I've been learning how to play the acoustic guitar for around a year and want to try an electric guitar. I don't seem to be able to decide upon a guitar as there are so many options.

Comment: Go out to shops and play as many guitars as you can. Don't rush it, and eventually one will pick you. And remember that this decision isn't final: you can always trade or sell and get another guitar, or don't and start a collection.

Comment: Your teacher should be a good guide, and maybe have several examples to let you try. That's what I do. What do you mean, you haven't got a teacher...?

Comment: First question: What is your budget? Next question: What type of music interests you? That would rule out many options that are confusing you: Different types of electrics are designed to facilitate  playing  certain types of music. For example, large hollow bodied models with minimal electronics are often tailored for jazz players, while smaller, thin models heavy on electronics are more suited for hard rock and shredding, etc.  Others -
 the Fender Stratocaster for example - might be considered "all purpose". (As a beginner, you'd probably do best with an 'all purpose' type of guitar.)

Answer (score 5):

Everybody has their personal preference's because that's what they feel comfortable playing! I'd suggest you do the same, there's nothing beneficial about saving up for a guitar that works for your guitar hero and then it not being practical for you and where you are at as a musician - trust me, I've failed miserably at this and it is a common amateur mistake, learn from my mistake. I'd suggest to go to music stores in your local area and simply sit down, try out some that look appealing to you. Even if the shop owner doesn't like that guitar (for other than tech glitches/issues), that doesn't mean you don't have to like it too. He'll probably be stuck in mainstream guitar preference and that's something you must not be poisoned by before you buy your first electric guitar!

Look for these things when buying your electric guitar. Make sure you have no external influences when thinking about these questions, it has to be 100% personal:

1. Does this look appealing to me?
2. Does this feel comfortable? (string action and gauge can be changed so mainly focus on the body and neck)
3. Can I see myself playing this?
4. Can I afford it?

If it's a yes from all, then buy it! Second hand guitars are more affordable too, pre-loved instruments are sometimes considered better in feeling because they are worn in. Remember, playing well is all in the fingers. I've seen guys shred and sound better than I ever can and they were rocking a $150 electric guitar.

Comment: I'd love to make this answer more of a community answer as many people face the same situation, so feel free to add any more pre-purchase questions in the comments.

Comment: There's always my mantra: find a pre-loved one, pay a lot less and get your money back if it turns out it isn't exactly what you thought you needed. And often, it'll be a well sorted guitar, set up nicely. If not, there's even more bargaining power !

Comment: Tom Morello won his first Grammy while playing a 200 dollar guitar as his main axe, an expensive guitar is only worth it if you are searching for that elusive last 2 percent in guitar tone.

Comment: I would add than when you play the right one, you know it in your bones. Then you have to be bold and look at the price and hope it's affordable. The other way to go is to buy something affordable and grow to love it.

Comment: Great bullet points - but maybe #4 should really be #1.

Comment: @Stinkfoot Maybe, but it being number 4 would inspire someone to save up for a great purchase.