# Buying a classical guitar

Tags: classical-guitar

Do you have any brand suggestions for a classical guitar in the price range 500-1000 dollars? Am I better off buying a factory produced guitar or handmade (if there are handmade guitars this cheap)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Unfortunately, asking suggestions about specific equipment is considered off topic for this site. In the meantime, I recommend you to follow the [tour] and read [ask] good questions.

Comment: However, there are some previous posts with advice about choosing a guitar:
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/how-do-you-identify-a-good-acoustic-guitar
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/979/how-do-i-choose-my-first-guitar-for-self-learning
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/63631/how-should-i-go-about-buying-a-guitar
Especially in a low price range, there are many good factory-made models and many bad handmade instruments. Most of all, be sure you're buying from a dealer who already does that filtering for you. If possible, play before you buy.